# Matlab default color space & working with YUV

Tags: matlab, rgb, yuv

I am interested in working with YUV color space images in Matlab, but (correct me if I'm wrong) I believe the default color space Matlab works with is RGB?

Therefore, I may be misleading myself thinking I'm operating on the luminance (Y) channel for example when I'm actually working on the red (R) channel. Am I correct? Is it possible to change the color space being used?

I am aware of conversions, but at the moment I'm curious if it is possible to tell Matlab to work with the YUV colour space and, for example, simply alter the luminance channel in one line (instead of altering the red intensity if RGB).

I've come across: http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/returnedcolorspace.html (ReturnedColorSpace), but I don't understand how to implement it.

Edit:

```
t = Tiff('e82.tiff','r');
[Y,Cb,Cr] = read(t);
close(t)

figure; imshow(Cr);
```

I've also tried this code in Matlab, but I'm not sure if I am right to assume it is reading the Cr channel as greyscale because it is assuming RGB color space involved? (The figure displays a greyscale version of the image)

EDIT (28/3/16) - imfinfo output of my YUV file.

```
                 FileSize: 353500
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 720
                   Height: 243
                 BitDepth: 24
                ColorType: 'YCbCr'
          FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: [8 8 8]
              Compression: 'PackBits'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'YCbCr'
             StripOffsets: [1x49 double]
          SamplesPerPixel: 3
             RowsPerStrip: 5
          StripByteCounts: [1x49 double]
              XResolution: 72
              YResolution: 72
           ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: [255 255 255]
           MinSampleValue: [0 0 0]
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 353302
                 Software: 'Lavc56.60.100'
         YCbCrSubsampling: [2 1]
      ReferenceBlackWhite: [15 235 128 240 128 240]
```

However, the following snippet of code writes "Y" "U" "V" images as if they're RGB (each output is a greyscale version of each RGB colour channel)

```
a = imread('3d008.tiff');
a1 = a(:,:,1); imwrite(a1,'xdel1.tiff');
a2 = a(:,:,2); imwrite(a2,'xdel2.tiff');
a3 = a(:,:,3); imwrite(a3,'xdel3.tiff');
```

Converting this "YUV" image to YUV (via rgb2yuv code) and repeating the above 4 lines of code outputs what I visually expect. a1 being a luminance channel and the others being chrominance.

Comment: I have problems understanding your question. If you read a RGB image, what else than converting the colour space do you want to do to get YUV?

Comment: Sorry. I am reading a YUV color space image (tiff format) and want to perform operations on it. Without doing anything, are operations working with the YUV or RGB system? For instance, U goes from -128 to 128 I believe for YUV and G goes from 0 to 255 for RGB. So there would be differences depending on the operations I do. I'm uncertain if Matlab by default is working with RGB or actually recognises it is YUV and works with YUV. @Daniel

Comment: @DragonDance27 can you post the output of `imfinfo` on your image?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've edited the question to include imfinfo's output and an explanation of how it appears to not be YUV images. @Amro

Answer (score -3):

Reading trough this page I will suggest

http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/specifying-the-color-space.html

```
I = imread('image.tiff');
I.ReturnedColorSpace = 'YCbCr';
```

Comment: `ReturnedColorSpace` is a property of `videoinput` objects. `imread` does not return `videoinput` objects.

Comment: You are mixing the Image Processing Toolbox and Image Acquisition Toolbox together.  You can't do this with `imread`.  `imread` simply returns a raw matrix of pixels.  What is returned **is not an object / structure** so this assignment is invalid.